# How to use onclick on a button with an insert function for multiple buttons php

Tags: php, ajax, button, onclick

I have a page with several buttons whose values and names are retrieved from the database.  I'm trying to run an insert query on any button clicked, my code so far:

```
<?php
$sqlGetIllness = "SELECT * FROM illnissesandconditions "; 
$resultGetIllness = $conn->query($sqlGetIllness);
while ($rowGetIllness= mysqli_fetch_array($resultGetIllness)){
    echo "<div class='col-md-3'style='margin-top:20px;'><button onclick='insert(".$rowGetIllness['illness'].");' class='button button1' style=' color:white;' value='".$rowGetIllness['illness']."'>".$rowGetIllness['illness']."</button></div>";
}

function insert($value) {
    $value='';
    $sqlGetId = "SELECT commonID from common group by commonID DESC LIMIT 1 "; 
    $resultGetId = $conn->query($sqlGetId);
    $r=mysqli_fetch_array($resultGetId);
    $id=$r['commonID'];

    $sqlGetIllness = "INSERT INTO medicalrecords (CommonID,Medical_Condition) VALUES (".$id.",'".$value."')"; 
    $resultGetIllness = $conn->query($sqlGetIllness);
}
```

The value passed to the function inside `onclick` is correct when I inspect it in the browser, however nothing happens.  I have a database connection on already, what could be wrong? Is it possible to do it like that in php without refreshing the page? Or do I need to use a client side lang like AJAX? Please note that I've never worked in AJAX btw.

**New EDIT:**

```
<script>
    $("button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        data: { 
            condition: $(this).val(), // < note use of 'this' here

        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('Condition Inserted!');
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});



</script>
```

**Solution:**
I got it worked out, after writing the script, i retrieved the variable value on top of the page

```
if (isset($_POST['condition'])) {
    $value=$_POST['condition']; }
```

inside `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )` and now it inserts the value when ever any button is clicked, my next step is to give the clicked button a background color

Comment: Correct, You either need to refresh the page with a GET/POST request or evoke a client side AJAX call. You can't call a PHP function from the browser like you're expecting. Put it this way, once the html has hit the browser, there's no going back to your PHP script.

Comment: Ah okay i see, i'll probably research a way to do in ajax then, the thing is i have alot of buttons, and i want them directly to insert when ever any is selected (1 or more), thank you for the clarification

Comment: @Scuzzy i have edited my post with new code/script used, could you take a look and reply back please ?

Comment: @Scuzzy Got it worked out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is in the post under `Solution`, was my first time trying ajax and it did work indeed, gave the button an id, and took its value ( any button clicked ) through this.val and sent via post, retrieved and used the value in a variable for the insert query.